# Simple router with two ethernet interface no static route needed?

Tags: routing, subnet, routeros

Normaly, for two subnets connected with one router, i always used to create two routes

per example:

**subnet 1:** 192.168.1.0/24
**subnet 2:** 192.168.2.0/24

**router interface 1:** 192.168.1.99
**router interface 2:** 192.168.2.99

**route 1:** dst-adress 192.168.2.0/24 gateway: 192.168.1.99
**route 2:** dst-adress 192.168.1.0/24 gateway: 192.168.2.99

So far so good, i can ping subnet 1 from subnet 2 and vice versa

i am using routerOS from microtik and just realised, that the routing also works **without** any static route. Is this an automation from routerOS or is that normal with any router wich has only two network interfaces?

i am confused,
Thank you

Comment: Routers inherently know about directly attached networks, so static routes for those are not necessary. Routers learn routes in three ways: directly connected networks, statically configured routes, or through a routing protocol. The last two are only necessary for non-attached networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Post your comment as answer to be upvoted :)

Comment: @Khaled, OK, it's done.

Answer (score 4):

Routers inherently know about directly attached networks, so static routes for those are unnecessary. Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through a routing protocol

The last two are only necessary for non-attached networks.